# Not returning Restangular back-end call correctly

Tags: angularjs, restangular

My back-end call is returning `undefined`. A.k.a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. I think I am calling it incorrectly.

**Here is the AngularJS controller code:**

```
$scope.addUser = function (chaseUser) {
    Accounts.addChaseUser(userToSubmit).then(function (response, err) {
        if (err) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "There was an error.";
            $log.debug(err);
        } else if (response) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "It worked.";
            $log.debug(response);
        } else {
            $scope.errorMessage = "No 'response' nor 'err' returned from backend";
        }
    });
};
```

How this responds is that if...

***(1)*** I put in correct credentials, I get a `response` that comes back with all the transaction data but still `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in the console.

***(2)*** Input incorrect credentials, I get no error object, response object, or even making it down to the line where I have `$scope.errorMessage = "No 'response' nor 'err' returned from backend";` **plus**, of course, `cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

**Corresponding AngularJS service:**

```
return {
    addChaseUser: function(credentials) {
        return Restangular.one('user').customPOST(credentials, 'addUser');
    }
};
```

**On the backend (controller):**

```
module.exports = {

   addChaseUser: function (req, res) {
      PlaidService.provideCredentialsToMFA(req.body, function (err, mfaRes) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(403).json(err);
        }
        return res.json(mfaRes);
      });
    },

 };
```

**Backend service:**

```
var plaid = require('plaid');
var plaidClient = new plaid.Client('test_id', 'test_secret', plaid.environments.tartan); 

module.exports = {
  provideCredentialsToMFA: function (credentials, cb) {
    Q.fcall(PlaidService.connectUser.bind(this, credentials))
      .then(PlaidService.saveUsersAccessToken.bind(this, credentials))
      .then(PlaidService.getTransactionData.bind(this, credentials))
      .then(function(transactions) {
        cb(null, transactions);
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        cb(err, null);
      });
  },

}
```

How am I supposed to be calling this Restangular `POST` from the AngularJS controller? It should not be returning undefined.

Comment: Undefined is undefined. What does `addUser` return? (Well, it doesn't ..)

Comment: Either the `err` object, or the `mfaRes`

Comment: That is not correct; hence the exception. The JavaScript engine is correctly reporting the problem - don't doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are getting the response from the server side, it means that your server side code and the angular service code is working just fine. :)

The only possibility I can see is that I is wrong with the application of `.then()` block is that insted of two parameters(i.e., response and err) lets try with only one parameter.

Something like following :

```
    $scope.addUser = function (chaseUser) {
        Accounts.addChaseUser(userToSubmit).then(function (response) {
            if(response.status == 'error'){
               $log.debug('Got error in the response');
            }else{
               $log.debug('SUCCESS');
            }
        });
    };
```

I have used `.then(function(data))` with only one parameter. That is the only thing I could find  :)

Comment: ok, that is probably the best I am going to be able to do for now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Incase you still don't see it, you are missing a few returns in your functions.

```
addUser: function (req, res) {
   return PlaidService.provideCredentialsToMFA(
       // ... your code ...
      );
},
```

`provideCredentialsToMFA` should return the promise

```
provideCredentialsToMFA: function (credentials, cb) {
  return plaidClient.addConnectUser(
       // ... Your code ...
      );
}
```

EDIT:
simplifying the working code looks something like this. Notice there are no returns and only callbacks are used:

```
  findChargeById: function (req, res) {
    fetchCharge(someParams, someCallBack);
  }

  fetchCharge: function (chargeId, cb) {
    stripe.charges.retrieve(chargeId, anotherCallBack);
  }
```

Your code looks like this. It's similar but the `$scope.addUser` expects something returned and doesn't use a callback

```
   addUser: function (req, res) {
      provideCredentialsToMFA(someParams, someCallBack);
      // addUser returns nothing
   }

   provideCredentialsToMFA: function (credentials, cb) {
     plaidClient.addConnectUser(someParams, someCallBack);
     // provideCredentialsToMFA returns nothing and it seems plaidClient.addConnectUser returns nothing too
   }


$scope.addUser = function (userInfo) {
    // Here is the difference with your 'then' call. Accounts.addUser doesn't return anything and takes 2 params
    Accounts.addUser(userInfo).then(someCallBack);
};
```

Comment: When I do that I actually get the same error :/ so confused

Comment: @ZachCook does `plaidClient.addConnectUser` return anything?

Comment: Well, this is what it says about the `plaidClient.addConnectUser` in the docs.

Comment: // addConnectUser(String, Object, Object?, Function)  
plaidClient.addConnectUser(institution_type, credentials, options, callback);

Comment: If it doesn't return anything then you'll have to change your chain of function calls to use callbacks like the example you gave that works

Comment: The problem is, I cannot tell what the substantive difference is between my code, and the example I was following.